# Making string output to terminal undeletable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on making a ruby cli project. Was trying to make a nice prompt to user just like the once we see in windows and Linux terminals like

```
ruby-docs>>
```

using print works fine but the line printed can be deleted by user, is there any way to freeze this line so it can't be modified when printed to terminal

Comment: Tip: Use the [Readline](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html) module.

Comment: Interesting, what platform? A quick test of `print("Prompt?"); result = gets.chomp` would not allow me to delete the prompt.